# Getting a MatrixTransform for any Transform

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I'm working within the WPF stack, and I'd like to be able to get a MatrixTransform for any Transform. According to the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), it doesn't seem that MatrixTransform is a base class but rather a sibling to the other Transform types. However, all normal graphics transforms should boil down to a MatrixTransform. Are there any shortcuts for this? Maybe something like hidden cast operators to take any transform to a MatrixTransform?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The base class of `TranslateTransform`, `MatrixTransform`, etc. is the abstract class `Transform`.

The `Transform` class exposes a `Value` property of type `Matrix`.  The `MatrixTransform` class has a constructor that takes a `Matrix`.  So to get the general `MatrixTransform` corresponding to an existing `LayoutTransform` of a `FrameworkElement` you can use code like this:

```
var transform = new MatrixTransform(element.LayoutTransform.Value);
```

Comment: Fantastic! That's just what I was looking for.

Comment: GeneralTransform doesn't have the Value property.