# Convert GeneralTransform to MatrixTransform in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, transform, matrix-transform

In full .net I can convert GeneralTransform to MatrixTransform with code (look to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237438/getting-a-matrixtransform-for-any-transform)):

```
var matrixTransform = new MatrixTransform(generalTransform.Value);
```

But in WinRT GeneralTransform haven't `Value` property. How I can do converting in WinRT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the full .NET version (WPF, Silverlight) the [`GeneralTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.generaltransform.aspx) class does not have a `Value` property either. This property is introduced in the [`Transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.aspx) class which *derives* from `GeneralTransform`. I suppose that's the same in WinRT. It is generally not possible to convert a `GeneralTransform` to a `MatrixTransform`because the transformation of a `GeneralTransform` must no necessarily be based on (or can be expressed as) a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
transformGroup.Children.Add(generalTransform);
var matrixTransform = new MatrixTransform();
matrixTransform.Matrix = transformGroup.Value;
```